# Terms in AVFoundation Programming guide are confusing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avkit

I'm reading AVFoundation Programming guide by apple

but i cannot figure out exactly what is "presentation" state and "track"

In this paragraph

***"To control the playback of assets, you use an AVPlayer object. During playback, you can use an AVPlayerItem instance to manage the presentation state of an asset as a whole, and an AVPlayerItemTrack object to manage the presentation state of an individual track. To display video, you use an AVPlayerLayer object."***

I can understand that `assets` are videos or audio files and but presentation state, is this just saying screen of assets now playing?

and tracks! they say assets are made by one or more tracks

if there is one video assets, is this made by audio part of video and only VIDEO part without sounds?